OpenVPN - Can I set up route metrics in the CLIENT config files?
Can I set them up in the client config files, or must they be on the server config file?
If so, would the below client config file work?
dev tun
tls-client

remote your-vpn-server.example.com 1194

# Prevent all traffic from being routed through the VPN by default
route-nopull

# Route all traffic to the home network (192.168.1.0/24) via the local network gateway when on the home network
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 net_gateway 5

# Route traffic to the server (192.168.1.238) through the VPN when not on the home network
route 192.168.1.238 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway 10

# Script security level to allow scripts to run if needed
script-security 2

# Pull other options from the server
pull

# Use UDP protocol
proto udp

I took a look at the documentation, https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage, and I'm quite confused as to whether this:

--route network/IP [netmask] [gateway] [metric] Add route to routing table after connection is established. Multiple routes can be
specified. Routes will be automatically torn down in reverse order
prior to TUN/TAP device close. This option is intended as a
convenience proxy for the route(8) shell command, while at the same
time providing portable semantics across OpenVPN's platform space.
netmask default -- 255.255.255.255
gateway default -- taken from --route-gateway or the second parameter
to --ifconfig when --dev tun is specified.
metric default -- taken from --route-metric otherwise 0.
The default can be specified by leaving an option blank or setting it
to "default".
The network and gateway parameters can also be specified as a DNS or
/etc/hosts file resolvable name, or as one of three special keywords:
vpn_gateway -- The remote VPN endpoint address (derived either from
--route-gateway or the second parameter to --ifconfig when --dev tun is specified).
net_gateway -- The pre-existing IP default gateway, read from the
routing table (not supported on all OSes).
remote_host -- The --remote address if OpenVPN is being run in client
mode, and is undefined in server mode.

goes into the server.config file via SSH (I'd use PuTTY as my SSH client of choice) or into the client config files imported by the OpenVPN GUI Client. The latter would be much preferred by me ofc.I use Synology NAS btw, that's what my OpenVPN Server runs on

Yes, you can set route metrics directly in the client configuration files. The example provided would work as intended.
